# Package inputenc Error: Unicode char T (U + 3A4)

Tags: packages, unicode

I have the following text

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{test}
\author{spanos.nikolaos }
\date{July 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}
\item genom-scores.csv: The tag genome is a data structure that contains tag relevance scores for movies. 
Τhe tag genome encodes how strongly movies exhibit particular properties represented by tags (atmospheric, thought-provoking, realistic, etc.). 
This file although downloaded was not used.
\item genom-tags.csv: The tag descriptions for the tag IDs in the genome file. Same as above, the file was not used further in our research.
\item links.csv: Identifiers that can be used to link to other sources of movie data are contained in the file links.csv.

Τhe number of misclassifications over the total number of predicted values. The zero-one loss is either served as a fraction, either as an integer number. The zero-one loss considers the entire set of labels for a given sample incorrect if it does not entirely match the true set of labels. Hamming loss is more forgiving in that it penalizes only the individual labels. 
(https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.zero\_one\_loss.html\#sklearn.metrics.zero\_one\_loss),
(https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.hamming\_loss.html)
The calculation formula to compute the zero-one loss is similar to the one used for computing the Hamming loss. However, as already mentioned, in multi-classification experiments, the zero-one loss is more strict in calculating the miss-classification as the entire array of predicted values should exactly match the array of the true values. Hamming loss is illustrated as fraction and zero-one loss as an integer number.\newline\newline
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And when it is compiled in Overleaf, I get the following error(s):

[image]

Even though I searched about it, I couldn't find an answer that would suffice. I guess that if I can spot the error in that text, I can be aware of it and correct it. But for now, I can't find the root of the error.

Thank you in advance for any comment and for your help.

Comment: Off-topic: To properly typeset URL strings, *don't* escape TeX-special characters such as `#` and `_`. Instead, execute `\usepackage{xurl}` and `\urlstyle{same}` in the preamble and encase the URL strings in `\url{...}` "wrappers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See

https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?%CE%A4he

You have written "The" with a Greek Tau instead of a Latin T, just delete the word and retype it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Mr.David. I will make use of the link you posted, so I can spot similar cases in the future. Based on your answer the unicode error is when a non-English letter is written, right?

Comment: @NikSp well as the error message says you can set up non English letters, If you were typing Greek text you would want to use a Greek package that defined these for you, but here the error is good if you had defined the character you would have no error message but incorrect output.

Comment: @NikSp You don't need my unicode names page, the error message tells you the problem is U+03A4 which is Tau (not U+034A as you put in the title) and it shows by the linebreak the exact point in the file where the unknown character is at the T in The.